# Mime type from file

Tags: java, file, mime

I need to find the Mime type of a file I receive as base 64 in java.
I need to define various types of files like doc, xls, jpg, png, htm, csv etc...
I tried to use tika but I am getting for .doc file the mime application/x-tika-ooxml which is not helpful.
I tried sending tika File or InputStream or TikaInputStream and I am getting the same result. Any Ideas?

Comment: Of course decode base64 first for binary data. The first kilobyte should suffice.

Comment: what is your domain? do you have to cover ALL MIMEs or are you interested only in a small subset?

Comment: Many formats stick their interesting header data at very end of a file (example: zip); not all of those are fully detectable if you don't have the very end of the file. 95%+ is detectable based off of the first kb, but not everything.

Comment: I don’t need all type of files i need jpg, png, htm, doc, docx, xls, tiff, pdf, csv,rtf,png.

Comment: I rather not go over the byte array and check it, If there is more readable way, I think it would be better. I am though it would be a simple task that I would find many answers in google, but I am working on it for a few days and still didn’t find a simpler answer

Comment: If you;re in *nix, look at the 'file' command and how it works